# Python loop for modbus

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

i have a modbus tcp/ip calorimeter from which i get values 1 or 0..

Each time calorimeter reaches 10kw it signals "0" otherwise its 1

In python i want script to run all the time and record / calculate each 10 kilowats.

Example:

```
Current kw: 260000 (manually read it from calorimeter and enter it to python)

Signal "0" (reached 10kw) - time 10:23

Signal "0" (reached 10kw) - time 10:35

Signal "0" (reached 10kw) - time 10:41

current kw: 260030
times reached 10kw: 3x
```

Problem is that when calorimeter reaches 10 kilowats it signals multiple zeros at same time and python sums all of them instead of only 1

Example:

```
1
1
1
1
0 (calorimeter reaches 10kw)
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
```

What should i do so i could read only first zero for each signal or how else could i calculate this?

Current code:

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient
from datetime import datetime

IP = '192.168.22.95'
client = ModbusTcpClient(IP)

current_kw = 260000

while True:

    a = client.read_holding_registers(0, 1)
    b = a.registers

    if b[0]==0:
        date = datetime.now()
        current_kw += 10
        print (current_kw, "kW")
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the calorimeter brand and model so I don't accidentally buy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good way to solve this would be by keeping the status from previous reading and adding 10 kW only if previous state was 1.

Set the new variable

```
client = ModbusTcpClient(IP)
last_state = 1
current_kw = 260000
```

And check for change in status in the if

```
if b[0]==0 and last_state==1:
```

Don't forget to set the variable on the end of while loop to last read state.

```
last_state=b[0]
```

Final code would look like this.

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient
from datetime import datetime

IP = '192.168.22.95'
client = ModbusTcpClient(IP)
last_state = 1
current_kw = 260000

while True:

    a = client.read_holding_registers(0, 1)
    b = a.registers

    if b[0]==0 and last_state==1:
        date = datetime.now()
        current_kw += 10
        print (current_kw, "kW")
    last_state=b[0]
```

Comment: Good approach, also thought about this kind of [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern#What_problems_can_the_Memento_design_pattern_solve?). Why not illustrate in your example code (after your if) instead keeping in mind: `last_state = b[0]`.

Comment: @hc_dev Yeah, that would be smart. Had to finish my coffee to realize that. Edited answer to reflect that.